# Find orientation angle of a cylinder in 3d space

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I have a cylindrical object in 3D space XYZ. Center of mass of the cylinder is I and some point at the the top of my cylinder is J. Point I and j both are on the axis of cylinder and the cylinder is symmetrical. I know the coordinates of I an J. [image]
My cylinder can rotate and translate in 3d space. How can I calculate $\theta$ and $\phi$ in spherical coordinate system from Cartesian coordinate with respect to I(COM of cylinder) and with respect to O which is (0,0,0). From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system), I can see the basic conversion from Cartesian to spherical coordinate but not being able to use in my case. Some hints or explanation will be helpful. Please follow any XYZ of any one picture.
[image]

Comment: Is $J$ on the axis of the cylinder? Is the cylinder circularly symmetric around the axis? If not, note that if $I$ and $J$ are given, you can rotate the cylinder around the $IJ$ line, so your solution is not unique

Comment: yes J on the axis of the cylinder..and it is circularly symmetric..so rotating around IJ won't have any effect.I have edited the question based on your suggestion.. thanks.

Comment: All you need is to use the relative position of $J$ to $I$. So take $(x,y,z)=(x_J-x_I,y_J-y_I, z_J-z_I)$ and plug these into the formula from wikipedia

Comment: thanks..why do i need to take difference between to point? is it for making a vector?

Comment: Because you asked for the orientation of the cylinder **with respect to COM**. So you need to write the coordinate of $J$ in the system defined by $I$

Comment: thank you sir..things are quite clear now.. So if I want to calculate orientation with respect to O (0,0,0) in that case I should do (x,y,z) = (0 -xi, 0-yi,0-zi). Am I correct.

Comment: The order is reversed: $x_I-0$ and so on. This will give you the position of COM, which you transform to angles.